# Timeout when calling async method on a WCF proxy

Tags: .net, wpf, wcf, asynchronous, async-await

I am trying to test a tiny WCF service I have built, from a WPF client, and I get a `TimeoutException` when I call an async method on the service proxy:

```
async void ExecuteProcessNowCommand()
{
    try
    {
        await _proxy.ProcessAsync(true);
    }
    catch (FaultException<FaultExceptionData> fix)
    {
        MessageBoxFacility.ProcessingError(fix.Detail.ExceptionType + ": " + fix.Detail.Message, fix.Detail.StackTrace);
    }
}
```

This code is from my viewmodel, in response to a button's command.

The exception in unhandled, and not coming through the `FaultException`. What is actually timing out here? I had assumed await would not block and get a timeout, so I suspect it's somewhere else, but could `await` maybe cause the timeout? The exception message is:

> An exception of type 'System.TimeoutException' occurred in
>   mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: The HTTP request to
>   'http://localhost:8089/TestService/SchedulerService/' has exceeded the
>   allotted timeout of 00:01:00. The time allotted to this operation may
>   have been a portion of a longer timeout.

The WCF is hosted in a Windows service, which is running when the method is called. Where should can I start looking to diagnose this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[WCF has a timeout on many operations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh924831%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). It doesn't matter whether the operation is `async` or not. Most WCF timeouts are of one minute by default, which fits with your exception.

The available timeouts are:

1. OpenTimeout
2. CloseTimeout
3. SendTimeout
4. ReceiveTimeout

In your case the relevant timeout is probably SendTimeout as the operation probably exceeds a minute.

This exception, `System.TimeoutException`, will not be under `FaultException` as it's a client side exception, it doesn't come from the server.

If you want to handle this exception you need add an appropriate catch clause. To get rid of this exception you need to either make sure the operation doesn't exceed the allotted time or increase the timeout configuration to a more reasonable value.

Comment: Thanks. I will give it a whirl quite soon, but you've given me some good starting points for a very harried and hurried brain.